# Performance issue on Oracle Linux with VB6 client application

Tags: linux, oracle, vb6

I have a Linux server which is hosting a Oracle database and there are around 500 client applications written in VB6 that connect to this Linux server. When the number of users are down to lets say under 20 the application runs Fast enough for all the clients but as the number of users grow the applications becomes slower and slower to a stage where it is almost unusable. I have debugged the application and it looks like database /server is the bottle neck. How can I debug the exact issue and resolve?

Comment: What have you tried?  Depending on the Oracle version, edition, licensed option(s) and what is installed, I'd probably want to start with an AWR or a Statspack report from when performance is acceptable and when it is slow to look to see what wait events are elevated.  That assumes, though, that you are licensed to use the AWR or that you have installed Statspack.  Beyond that, you can trace an individual session to look at the different wait events when performance is acceptable and unacceptable.

Comment: you can start checking oracle DB is shared server or dedicated server . how much resource is available in DB it terms of RAM & CPU , check Load avg from sar report.